# Trouble using Tensorflow: SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3

I'm trying to use the LSTM neural network found here on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

I have trouble running the program, since I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malasartes/canigo/model-1/model-1.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have read here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690 that there seems to be a problem with the word **async**, being a keyword. But when I change the keyword to **async1** I get another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: invalid ELF header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malasartes/canigo/model-1/model-1.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: invalid ELF header


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

What seems to be the problem now?

Using:

-Raspberry Pi 4 model B with Raspbian OS 64 bits

-Python 3.9.3

-Tensorflow 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImportError: /home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: invalid ELF header
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This implies you are using binaries not compiled for the Pi, meaning you installed the wrong tensorflow package.

You can confirm this with `file /home/malasartes/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so`.  The response should begin with (after the path):

```
ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The important bit is indicated.  If that isn't there or it is something else (eg. `x86-64`), the problem is as just described.